# IIS error in sharepoint web appliction , How to create it

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I am SharePoint newbie when I created a new web application that created
 without any error but when I browse it I got

> 404 not found

I tried to create another new web application but I got the same error.

I don't know what's the root cause ?! Please help ?

Thanks Ali

Comment: try to run iisreset

Comment: Yes i did but i got the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this issue might occur if you create a web application without creating a **site collection** so make sure that the web application has a site collection as the following:

- Open Central Administration > Application Management > View all site collections > Select your web application and check if it has a site collection or not !

If it does not have a site collection ,  try to create a site collection for this web application as the following:

- Open Central Administration > Below Application Management > Click on Create site collection.
- Make sure that the selected web application is the web application that not have a site collection.

[image]

- Fill the data that you need and select your site template > then click on OK.
- After the site collection has been created successfully try to browse the site URL , that should be now worked properly .

**Note :** you should be aware of When you try to create a web application and after it created successfully , you should get a dialog that informs you the `application created` , and you should click on create site collection link to create a site collection as shown below.

[image]